# How to get expandable rows from xlsx-file with group/level filter by PhpOffice/PhpSpreadSheet?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

The xlsx-file contains rows on three levels.
Records from level one: click on plus expands rows from level two.
Records from level two: click on plus expands rows from level three.

I'm using PhpOffice\PhpSpreadSheet.

How to get rows only from level two from xlsx-file by PhpOffice/PhpSpreadSheet, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Was solved by using code below

$depthLevel = $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($row)->getOutlineLevel();